# Weblogic 12c - How to prevent server.out file from rotating on MS restart

Tags: logging, jvm, weblogic, stdout

There is an option in Weblogic to prevent log rotation for a managed server during startup - is there a way to prevent the server.out files from being rotated as well?

I utilize logrotate to handle rotation and compression of the server.out files and this is nice and clean.  However, if a managed server is restarted the .out file is rotated and then I end up with servername_MS_01.out0000?/ servername_MS_02.out0000? files.  I have added functionality to logrotate to rotate these files as well, but I would prefer the .out files from rotating on a managed server restart, so I can have one single daily compressed file.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `<weblogic home>/common/bin/wlscontrol.sh` file. You will see a section with the following comment:

```
#
# Rotate the specified log file. Rotated log files are named
# <server-name>.outXXXXX where XXXXX is the current log count and the
# highest is the most recent. The log count starts at 00001 then cycles
# again if it reaches 99999.
#
save_log()
{
```

You can change that function to do whatever you want or simply comment out the `mv` command so that it does not rename/move the file.

You will probably find this thread useful as well. [Rotating .out files](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2388085)

Comment: I first commented out the mv command and this had no impact on the operation.  Once a MS is restarted, I am still seeing $name.out0000x files being generated.  I then proceeded to comment out the entire "save_log" function and it's reference within the wlscontrol.sh script.  I restarted nodemanager for grins, yet the .out files are still being rotated.  To clarify, I am using Weblogic 12c and Admin server to stop/start MS for my test.

Comment: Something else to try - add `-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true` to your startWebLogic.sh file. Here is another good resource: http://robin4444.blogspot.com/2011/11/rotate-out-log-files.html

Comment: Hmm, if "Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true" is utilized, I was under the impression that the server.out files would no longer exist? I guess I could change my logrotate.d files but the preferred method would to keep them separated. Restarted the Admin server with no impact as well.  Not sure why wlscontrol.sh script is not being referenced for this operation.  Something must have changed in 12c.